# When you meet an overseas colleague whom you've been contacting only via email

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, idiom-request, greetings, sayings

Let's say this is the first time you meet a certain colleague of the overseas branch in person, but you have been already communicating with them only via email several times for the past two years. Could you tell me some useful phrases to greet them professionally in that case?

Comment: What have you tried?  I'd suggest "good morning", or "nice to meet you".  I'm not sure why you'd need any special phrases in this situation.

Comment: Possibly "Nice to see you face to face at last" or something similar.